# How can I smoothly transition from one JFrame into another?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm trying to move from a title screen into the main program. I was going to simply set a button to create a new `JFrame` and close the previous however upon research this is said to be bad practice and the result isn't as seamless as I would hope. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try set focus?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JFrame is a window, when you use applications they do not typically open up a new window every time you change to a new view. Instead, you should have one JFrame and set up multiple JPanels. This way you can add the correct JPanel to the JFrame when needed.

To do this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(titlePanel); //menuPanel refers to a panel you create
```

Then when your button is clicked:

```
frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
frame.revalidate();
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late comment. How would I do this using an external plugin which automatically creates the JFrame :                                                                                                                            *`/**
  * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    StaffList2WithBetterSaveGUI inst = new StaffList2WithBetterSaveGUI();
    inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    inst.setVisible(true);
   }
  });
 }` *

Comment: @HS' you would do ```inst.getContentPane().removeAll();
inst.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
inst.revalidate(); inst.repaint();```

Comment: @chrissukhram If I was trying to "refresh" my frame doing ```frame.add(mainPanel); //... frame.getContentPane().removeAll(); frame.add(mainPanel); frame.revalidate(); frame.repaint();``` with `mainPanel` containing multiple nested `JPanels`, would those four statements also refresh the panels?